# Информация изображения по url

Tags: jquery, url, изображения

Как узнать размер изображения по его url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.width, this.height);
}

img.src = 'url';
```

Comment: @eicto %) я вторые сутки не сплю. Сначала вообще фигню какую-то написал.

Comment: Мне надо узнать его размер до загрузки на страницу.

Comment: Тогда вам уже нужно на сервере узнвать.

Comment: на странице она и не появится, она просто загрузится в память. потом можете вставить

Answer (score 1):

```
var loadImage = function (src, callback){
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = img.onerror = function (evt){
        callback(evt.type == 'error', img);
        img.onload = img.onerror = img = null;
    };
    img.src = src;
};
```

пример — http://jsfiddle.net/xeWzA/

Comment: не забываем делать проверку img.complete ! :)

Comment: Она тут не нужна.

Comment: вы правы, но почему ? всегда приходилось проверять complete, а тут вдруг и без него работает....

Comment: Всё просто, видно вы пытались назначить src до onload.

Comment: да нет, и так и так делал, причем, img.complete===true сразу после img.src = src; но onload срабатывает... щас в ie попробую протестить

Comment: Такое поведение было всегда, вот IE6 — http://www.rubaxa.org/screenshot/9c1ad8a9411658bd4e9f5caba96f.png